# How to use the results of a if statement to populate a column in a dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

The code that worked is at the bottom of this question as well as in the answers.

I would like to write a code that will run through each miRNA in my dataset "top.table" and then return whether the miRNA is up or down regulated or not significant by the logFC and P.Value for each miRNA.

If logFC is greater than 0.6 & P.Value is less than 0.05 this would be "Up Regulated".
If logFC is less than -0.6 and P.Value is less than 0.05 then this would be "Down Regulated".
If neither of these conditions are met these would be insignificant

I then want to take these results and add them to my data frame df which I am hoping to use cbind to add to the top.table data set

The column names for top.table are:

```
"miRNA"  "logFC"  "AveExpr"  "t"  "P.Value"  "adj.P.Val"  "B"
```

and within this data set I have 1068 miRNAs that I need to check individually

I am trying to create a new column in this table called Up_Down.Regulated so that I can visualise the results more easily.
I have tried running this code

```
df <- data.frame((matrix(nrow =1068, ncol = 1)), row.names = rownames(top.table))
colnames(df) <- "Up_Down.Regulated"
colnames(df)
colnames(top.table)
for (miRNA in top.table) {}
  if (top.table$logFC > 0.6 & top.table$P.Value < 0.05){
    df$Up_Down.Regulated == "UP"
  } else if (top.table$logFC < -0.6 & top.table$P.Value < 0.05){
      df$Up_Down.Regulated == "DOWN"
  }else {df$Up_Down.Regulated == "NonSig"
      }

  Error in if (top.table$logFC > 0.6 & top.table$P.Value < 0.05) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

What I want the code to do is run through each miRNA in the top.table dataset and then return whether the miRNA is up or down regulated or not significant, I then want to take these results and add them to my data frame df which I am hoping to use cbind to add to the top.table data set

This is the code that worked without creating the dataset and directly added the extra column to my original data set, thank you Andre Wildberg:

```
library(dplyr)

top.table %>% 
  mutate(Up_Down.Regulated = case_when(
                  logFC > 0.6 & P.Value < 0.05 ~ "UP", 
                  logFC < -0.6 & P.Value < 0.05 ~ "DOWN", 
                  TRUE ~ "NonSig"))
```

Comment: You are missing some parentheses. Also ...You apparently missed the section in the manual where the rules for valid column names were laid out. The only punctuation in "naked" column names are "_" and ".". You could get that code to succeed by putting in backticks, but it would makes so much sense to avoid all that future hassle and just switch to `up_down.Regulated` or similar.

Comment: R's loops are `for (miRNA in top.table) {}` while yours look like you're thinking Python. :)

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the column name but am getting the same error so I don't believe this was the main issue with my original code.

Comment: Thank you Roman, I have adjusted the code but am still getting a new Error: unexpected symbol in "  if logFC"

Comment: Please read carefully how to use `if` and `for` loops in R: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/control-structures-in-r-using-loops-and-if-else-statements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result is a vector use `ifelse` instead of `if` (which is what the error tries to say). On top of that using `dplyr`s `case_when` avoids having nested `else if`

```
library(dplyr)

top.table %>% 
  mutate(Up_Down.Regulated = case_when(
                  logFC > 0.6 & P.Value < 0.05 ~ "UP", 
                  logFC < -0.6 & P.Value < 0.05 ~ "DOWN", 
                  TRUE ~ "NonSig"))
```

Note: Untested because there's no example posted

Comment: Thank you for your response, the dataset I am using is from a genome wide study and had required multiple steps involving the Limma package for differential expression so apologies that the data was not included

Comment: @Sabrina No worries. It's just better in general if you break down the problem into a small minimal toy data set. That avoids a lot of misunderstandings and speeds up answers by an order of magnitude. Happy coding :)

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind for future questions, thank you 